# Synchronously loading an image by freezing the browser

Tags: javascript, image, synchronization, electron, freeze

I am using Electron framework in node.js to create a HTML5 Canvas game, I have mapped all of my resources into Atlases (one image containing sprites). Before the game is starting I want to load every `atlas.png`s into an object that continues to map all the atlases together so it is easier to use the images in the canvas element.

While doing this in Electron I was `unable` to *freeze* the `Electron BrowserWindow`. This makes my application/game just continue the code, or sometimes it stops.

```
this.addAtlas = function (name, root)
{
    // Creating the path for the Atlas
    var path = root + '/Assets/Atlases/' + name + '/' + name;


    // JSON File
    var jpath = path + '.json';

    // PNG File
    var ppath = path + '.png';

    // Checking if both png and json files exist
    if (!fs.existsSync(jpath) || !fs.existsSync(ppath) ) throw new Error('Atlas | "' + name + '" is not a valid Atlas (Misssing .json or/and .png file)');

    // Loading Atlas image syncrounously to Atlas.js
    var img = new Image(),
        isDone = false;

    // Initiating the Atlas
    img.onload = function () { isDone = true; };
    img.onerror = function () { throw new Error('Atlas | Atlas image failed to load!'); };
    img.src = ppath;

    // Stopping the browser to continue executing ANY scripts untill the image has finished loading.
    console.log('Started');

      ///////////////////////\\
     //    ATTENTION      //  \\
    ///////////////////////    \\
    // This is where my  \\    //
    // game is crashing   \\  //
    ///////////////////////////
    var count = 0;
    while (!isDone) {
        console.log(count);
        count++;
    }
    console.log('Finished');

    // Getting JSON file to an actual javascript object
    var obj = JSON.parse( fs.readFileSync(jpath).toString() );


    // Gathering all the information into an object
    var robj = {};

    robj.atlas = obj.Atlas;
    robj.image = img;
    robj.name = name;
    robj.id = this.atlasas_successully_loaded + 1;
    robj.path = path;

    // Injecting this.loaded with new Atlas
    this.loaded[robj.name] = robj;

    // Increasing the ID count
    this.atlases_successully_loaded++;
}
```

While this `while` loop is running there is absolutely no counting in the console, if I go check the `DOM Tree` there is no HTML, if I go to sources there is nothing. So how can I freeze the browser **UNTILL** the image / atlas is fully loaded?

Comment: a tight loop like that will of course freeze the page until the browsers tells you that your code is bad, and offers you the option to stop javascript - think of javascript as being single threaded - then learn how to work with asynchronous code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am guessing that you need the old setInterval trick here. Rather than having an infinite loop which blocks the execution stack from continuing you do something like this:

```
var interval;
interval = setInterval(function () {
    if (/*Some condition*/) {
        clearInterval(interval);
        nextFunction();
    }

}, 50) //check every 50 ms
```

It would be much better to do this with promises, but that would take a bit more work.

I think this is a working promise solution, although I did not study your code much, just kind of copy pasted and assumed it was the right idea.

```
this.addAtlas = function (name, root) {
    // Creating the path for the Atlas
    var path = root + '/Assets/Atlases/' + name + '/' + name;
     var that = this;

    // JSON File
    var jpath = path + '.json';

    // PNG File
    var ppath = path + '.png';

    // Checking if both png and json files exist
    if (!fs.existsSync(jpath) || !fs.existsSync(ppath) ) throw new Error('Atlas | "' + name + '" is not a valid Atlas (Misssing .json or/and .png file)');

    // Loading Atlas image syncrounously to Atlas.js

    var myPromise = function (resolve, reject) {
        var img = new Image(),
        isDone = false;

        // Initiating the Atlas
        img.onload = function () { resolve() };
        img.onerror = function () { reject('Atlas | Atlas image failed to load!'); };
        img.src = ppath;
    };

    // Stopping the browser to continue executing ANY scripts untill the image has finished loading.
    console.log('Started');

      ///////////////////////\\
     //    ATTENTION      //  \\
    ///////////////////////    \\
    // This is where my  \\    //
    // game is crashing   \\  //
    ///////////////////////////
    var count = 0;
    myPromise.then(function () {

        console.log('Finished');

        // Getting JSON file to an actual javascript object
        var obj = JSON.parse( fs.readFileSync(jpath).toString() );


        // Gathering all the information into an object
        var robj = {};

        robj.atlas = obj.Atlas;
        robj.image = img;
        robj.name = name;
        robj.id = this.atlasas_successully_loaded + 1;
        robj.path = path;

        // Injecting this.loaded with new Atlas
        that.loaded[robj.name] = robj;

        // Increasing the ID count
        that.atlases_successully_loaded++;
    });
};
```

Comment: I know that promises is better, but I ain't familiar with promises and just don't really understand them, using an interval is not *syncronously* doing a job. The code execution will still contuinue, which is bad for my end cause I need this to stop the code **untill** the atlas is **completely** loaded to the `this.loaded` array.

Comment: Yeah you make nextFunction do the next step in your code... JS works in an asyn nature, it is the only way around.

Comment: @TheTechCode I added a promise example. If you are calling this function a bunch then return the promise and the check to ensure it is all done you put all the promises in an array and say:

Promise.all(promiseArray).then(function () {...})

Comment: Turns out that your `myPromise` example almost turned to work my way. I did some flickering to the code and got it working to my needs. By the way, the next function could never have been a thing in what I am creating, because I am working with a library, not executable... +1 Thanks!

Comment: @TheTechCode no problem. You may want to do some reading on Promises and best practices. For instance you will need a catch on that promise in case something fails. Good luck with your game!